# Multiple Javascript function does not work at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have `<ul>` `<li>` lists. I created code that within all `<li>` checkbox checked message box will appear.

It works fine for first but does not works for the second list.

The other issue is on the page of the checkbox. The message will appear on any checkbox that's checked.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven");
    var Two = $("#eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve");
  
    $(function() {
        $(".chk-message16").hide();
        Onee.on('change', function() {
            if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 7) {
                $(".chk-message16").show();
            } else {
                $(".chk-message16").hide();
            }
        });
    });
  
    $(function() {
        $(".chk-message8").hide();
        Two.on('change', function() {
            if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 5) {
                $(".chk-message8").show();
            } else {
                $(".chk-message8").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="one"> one</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="two"> two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="three"> three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="four"> four</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="five"> five</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="six"> six</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="seven">seven</li>
    
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
    <div class="chk-message16">
        <h1>Message</h1>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</ul><br/><br/>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="eight">one</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="nine"> two</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="ten">three</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="eleven">four</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="twelve">five</li>
    
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
    <div class="chk-message8">
        <h1>Message</h1>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works well... What does "Do not work" mean?

Comment: It works fine, but I think your problem is when you check some of the `checkboxes` in the first group and some in the second. is that your problem?

Comment: It works only for first, Ul li section. If you check second one message box does not appear.  * also check 4 checkbox in first list and few from second one then too first message box appear.

Comment: Yes, @Algosub exactly, I want the message box should appear from particular ul li list. and all ul li list group should work

Comment: Then @Mohammad Yekta fixed you code correctly. The problem was with `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`. It caught all the checked `checkboxes` and not the ones in a specific group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fixed your code, by adding unique class for each list:  [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4fvujbLa/1/)

`list-1 AND list-2`

Comment: Why use jsfiddle instead of just copying the stack snippet and modifying it here?

Comment: There's a nice, big button that does it for you: **Copy Snippet to Answer**

Answer (score 0):

I may be late for the party, but here's a solution making it more general using list id, and taking in account whichever amount of checkboxes in that list:

```
var list1 = $('#list1').find('input[type=checkbox]');

list1.on('change', function() {
    if ($('#list1').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == list2.length) {
        $(".chk-message16").show();
    } else {
        $(".chk-message16").hide();
    }
});
```

See the snippet for full working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".chk-message16").hide();
    $(".chk-message8").hide();

    var list1 = $('#list1').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    var list2 = $('#list2').find('input[type=checkbox]');

    list1.on('change', function() {
      if ($('#list1').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == list2.length) {
        $(".chk-message16").show();
      } else {
        $(".chk-message16").hide();
      }
    });
    list2.on('change', function() {
      if ($('#list2').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == list2.length) {
        $(".chk-message8").show();
      } else {
        $(".chk-message8").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group" id="list1">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one">one</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="two">two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="three">three</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="four">four</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="five">five</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="six">six</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="seven">seven</li>
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
  <div class="chk-message16">
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul class="list-group" id="list2">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="eight">one</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nine">two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ten">three</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="eleven">four</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="twelve">five</li>
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
  <div class="chk-message8">
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should restrict your counting to just the particular set of inputs in each group.

And instead of hard-coding the lengths `7` and `5`, you can reverse the sense of the test -- if there are any unchecked boxes, hide the message box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var Onee = $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven");
  var Two = $("#eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve");

  $(function(){
    $(".chk-message16").hide();
    Onee.on('change', function() {       
      if(Onee.is(":not(:checked)")){
        $(".chk-message16").hide();
      }else{
        $(".chk-message16").show();
      }
    });
  });

  $(function(){
    $(".chk-message8").hide();
    Two.on('change', function() {       
      if(Two.is(":not(:checked)")){
        $(".chk-message8").hide();
      }else{
        $(".chk-message8").show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="one"> one</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="two"> two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="three"> three</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="four"> four</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="five"> five</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="six"> six</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="seven">seven</li>
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
  <div class="chk-message16">
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="eight">one</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="nine"> two</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="ten">three</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="eleven">four</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" id="twelve">five</li>
  <!-- if all selected show this message box-->
  <div class="chk-message8">
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</ul>
```